# Measure ActiveRecord performance in `limit` method

Tags: performance, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How can I measure ActiveRecord's performance?

My query has `where` and an `order by` clause, and on top of that I want the top row:

```
User.where(…).order(id: :asc).limit(1)
```

Knowing that the `order by` forces the parsing of the whole table, how much of a performance gain can there be in using `.limit(1)` as opposed to use `[1]`?

Comment: Convert the ORM request to an SQL one, and find the execution plan. I doubt having an ORDER clause on an indexed column will force the parsing of the entire table. (And I don't know the RoR ORM, but I wouldn't be surprised if `[1]` is handled just like `limit(1)`, that's what [the Django ORM does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574003/django-limiting-query-results))

Comment: I've been using the `.to_sql` conversion and it's been just about what I was looking for. Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting the ORM request to an SQL statement, although it is not a performance measure tool it can be used to inspect the SQL query. That alone for most cases is just about what one wants. (To me at least in the past ten days.)

```
> User.where(id: [10..50]).order(id: :asc).limit(1).to_sql
=> "SELECT  \"users\".* FROM \"users\"  WHERE ((\"users\".\"id\" BETWEEN 10 AND 50 OR 1=0))  ORDER BY \"users\".\"id\" ASC LIMIT 1"
```

This kind of output is a great starting point to improve one's ORM request.